# Detecting USB camera button event?

Tags: hardware, events

I'm trying to detect when the snapshot button of my USB camera is pushed.

Here are the infos I gathered about my camera with `cat /proc/bus/input/devices`:

```
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0c45 Product=6353 Version=0150
N: Name="USB Microscope"
P: Phys=usb-3f980000.usb-1.3/button
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/input/input14
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event0
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

No documentation nor identification is available about my specific model, as usual :)

I tried to listen /dev/input/event0 with `cat /dev/input/event0`, but, unlike mice or keyboards, i didn't see any result.
I also tried to listen this handler with python module evdev, without success ...

Did someone has a clue about this case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If clearly says `input14` (in the configuration after that particular boot, numberings can change), so of course looking at `event0` won't show anything.

1) Run `evtest` as root, see if you can figure out which device it is by looking at the description, and listen to it (my USB webcam produces `KEY_CAMERA`).

2) Run `xev`, move cursor into window, see if the event shows up (my USB webcam produces `XF86WebCam`).

3) You may need to activate your camera with `luvcview` or a similar program to make it produce events.

4) If you decide to use the input-layer interface, have a look at `/dev/input/by-id`, and if there's no entry, at `/dev/input/by-path` for symlinks to the `event*` devices that are guaranteed to be constant accross boots.

Comment: Wonderful, excellent, perfect ! both solution 1) and 4) are working out of the box, and now I understand better how events are linked. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Run vlc (or similar) and start video capture from webcam video device.
Without that I see no events with evtest and xev from the button.

Comment: Thanks! I have Microsoft LifeCam HD-5000 and it turns out that unless *video* capture is active, this button does not work. When I use the HD-5000 just as a microphone, the button does not emit anything. When video capture is active, `xev` correctly emits `XF86WebCam`.